# R time series dataset - Lag date and time - Irregular data periods

Tags: r

I am struggling with a dataset that includes **date** and **time**. I want to build new columns such as **same_period_previous_week** and **same_period_previous_day**.

I´ve read several answers here in Stackoverflow, but haven´t been able to fix it.

Here is a code to recreate my dataset:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("8/19/2018", "8/25/2018", "8/26/2018" ), class = "factor"), time = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L), value = c(2L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 7L, 14L, 21L)), .Names = c("date", "time", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
date       time value
8/26/2018   9   2
8/26/2018   10  15
8/26/2018   11  25
8/26/2018   12  35
8/25/2018   10  10
8/25/2018   11  20
8/25/2018   12  30
8/19/2018   10  7
8/19/2018   11  14
8/19/2018   12  21
```

I have tried using **dplyr**, first **ordering** the dataset, then **grouping** it and creating a **lagged** column. This is my code:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(date, time)
df_tmp <- df %>% group_by(date, time) %>% mutate(lag_1day = lag(value, n = 1, default = NA))
```

The new column (lag_1day) just ends up with several NAs.

I am hoping to get the following in result:

```
date    time    value   lag_1day
8/26/2018   9   2       NA
8/26/2018   10  15      10
8/26/2018   11  25      20
8/26/2018   12  35      30
8/25/2018   10  10      7
8/25/2018   11  20      14
8/25/2018   12  30      21
8/19/2018   10  7       NA
8/19/2018   11  14      NA
8/19/2018   12  21      NA
```

Notice that there is an NA for the first row, since there is no corresponding value at 9 am the previous day.

Does it matter if I arrange them in ascending or descending order in the first step?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. I think you were almost there.

```
library(dplyr)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y')

df %>%
  arrange(time, date) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(lag_1day = lag(value, n = 1, default = NA)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date, time))
```

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks for the really quick answer! Works great. 

So, I didn´t have to group by date and time?

Comment: The lag function works over a particular grouping. If you group by both date and time, each row isn't grouped with anything else, since date and time together are unique. If you group by just time, this groups all the dates together, and at which point your lag function will work correctly.